# How do I suppress warning : "struct xxyy declared inside parameter list"?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I want to use one of the options provided in the link below to suppress the warning:

> warning : struct xxyy declared inside parameter list

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Warning-Options.html

My requisite is to suppress this warning, not to fix it. Which option can I use from the above link?

Comment: I have seen that warning, but never in circumstances where it was reasonable to suppress or ignore it.  I'll not assist you in unleashing preventable software bugs on the world, nor even just on your colleagues.

Comment: you could `|grep -v "declared inside parameter list"` on the output of your compile line?

Comment: @J.Chomel haha, this must be the answer

Comment: Post code/relevant info  here.

Comment: You'll probably spend more effort trying to suppress the warning than you would if you simply fixed the cause.

Comment: Why don't you want to fix the offending code?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the warning fixing the issue. If the warning comes from something like:

```
void function(struct foo *x);
```

just put this line before:

```
struct foo;
```